# `sys.dont_write_bytecode` not working if I just import the function instead of the whole sys library

Tags: python, sys

I'm trying to delete the **`__pycache__`** folder for importing modules and if I:

```py
from sys import dont_write_bytecode 
dont_write_bytecode = True 

import folder.modulename as modulename
```

the folder still gets created, but if I import all the library as shown below:

```py
import sys 
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True 

import folder.modulename as modulename
```

the folder it's not created.

Can someone explain why this happens and if it's possible to avoid importing the whole **`sys`** library?

Comment: After `from sys import dont_write_bytecode`, you now have a variable named `dont_write_bytecode` in your own namespace, with (presumably) the value `False`.  Changing that variable's value has no conceivable effect on anything other than the variable itself; it certainly does not change the value in the `sys` module, which is still `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  When you write `from sys import dont_write_bytecode`, that creates a new name in your namespace and binds it to the same object as the one in `sys`.  When you write `dont_write_bytecode = True`, you are binding a different boolean object to your name, replacing your old binding.  It has absolutely no effect on the `dont_write_bytecode` variable that is part of `sys`.

However, to correct another misconception, using `from sys import xxx` is NOT any more efficient than `import sys`.

The import you have written is exactly equivalent to:

```
import sys
dont_write_bytecode = sys.dont_write_bytecode
del sys
```

The `from sys import` construct always has to import the entire module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm importing just what I need so I can save some space because for the program I'm using this in I have a limited amount of space so I'm trying to save as much as possible. I noticed you used the `del` keyword to delete the module. Does that help to save some space and remove the sys module after I used it?

Comment: @ersignee_: No, that just unassigns the name. You're not going to save the space you're trying to save. (In fact, `sys` has to be loaded by default for the Python interpreter itself to work, so even if you remove the import entirely, you still won't save that space. The module is already loaded, so all the import is doing is binding a name.)

Comment: Literally, `from sys import dont_write_bytecode` is EXACTLY the same as those three lines.